# Illegal Instruction :4

Tags: c, macos, terminal

i was writing a c code for executing "history 10" command of terminal,i run program using clang compiler on my mac terminal,it show error "Illegal Instruction :4"
My Code is-

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include<errno.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include<string.h>
int main()
{  char cmd[10];
   strcpy(cmd,"history 10");
       system(cmd); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need `char cmd[11];`  otherwise the NUL character (`'\0'`) is not stored.

Comment: *Off-by-one* error. (don't skimp on buffer size....)

Comment: Let the compiler do the work: `char cmd[] = "history 10";`

Comment: Please don't use both tags [tag:c] and [tag:c++]. These are different languages and your code is C-only,

Comment: Are you sure you need all those `*.h` files included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overrun your buffer: the `cmd` array has only 10 characters and you `strcpy` an 11-character string into it (the string has an implicit 11-th zero byte at the end, which is the string's terminator).

Get rid of the buffer and just do

```
 system("history 10");
```

Or declare the buffer long enough to accomodate your current, and possibly some future command. Something like this:

```
char cmd[500];
```